# Troubleshooting error when using markdown filter in Django template

Tags: django, markdown, markup, deprecated

When using the Markdown libraries I seem to get the following error:

> Error in 'markdown' filter: Django does not support versions of the
>   Python markdown library < 2.1.

As an example, it occurs on a tag such as:

```
{{ticket.get_description|markdown:"safe,footnotes,tables"}}
```

The `get_description` function is defined in the `Ticket` model. We've upgraded to Django 1.5 recently and the code was written pre Django 1.4. I've also upgraded the Markup library to 2.3.1 but the problem still persists. I've also cleared old .pyc files, just to be sure.

From what I've read, the `django.contrib.markup` libraries [have been deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/markup/). So, what would the suggested solution/alternative be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one idea is to install markdown2 library of python [see here](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2)
then you create your decorator

```
import markdown2
.. all other imports needed..

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def markdown2(value):
    return mark_safe(markdown2.markdown(force_unicode(value),safe_mode=True,enable_attributes=False))
```

then you use it

```
{% load myapp_markup %}
{{ value|markdown2 }}
```

code is adpated (and not tested) from [here](http://www.dominicrodger.com/django-markdown.html)

Comment: The author of python-markdown2 published a [django app based on python-mardown2](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux). With that app installed you can do `{{ value|markdown }}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update:

My decorator looks like this:

```
import markdown2
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def convertTxt(value):
    return mark_safe(markdown2.markdown(force_unicode(value)))

register.filter('convertTxt', convertTxt)
```

Also, I've noticed that it is not prudent to name your module or your method markdown2 :)